# Convert generic C# code to java

Tags: java, c#, generics

I need convert C# code to java:

```
public class TriggerWithParameters<TArg0> : TriggerWithParameters
{
    public TriggerWithParameters(TTrigger underlyingTrigger)
    : base(underlyingTrigger, typeof(TArg0))
    {
    }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
public class TriggerWithParameters1<TArg0> extends TriggerWithParameters
{
    public TriggerWithParameters1(TTrigger underlyingTrigger) {
        super(underlyingTrigger, howCanIgetHereTypeOfTArg0);
    }
}
```

But I have problem, I have no typeOf and I can't call no .class or getClass(), and I can't run no code before super statement.
How can I get type of TArg0 ?

Comment: Java does things differently. You'll need a `Class` object.

Comment: I have read this topic before, but it didn't help me, cause link that you gave me help to get type of object, but I can't write code before "super" statement. So I need to rewrite this C# function somehow to make it works.

Comment: What code do you need to write before `super`?